# How to put image in Rmardown?

Tags: html, r, image, shiny, r-markdown

I have a little problem with my R Markdown's file, I want to put an image on it.

I have used this code:

```
![Figure 2 : Modèle de *Dysdera crocata*, prédateur du cloporte *Armadillidium vulgare*-les flèches en vert indiquent les paramètres pouvant influencer positivement les effectifs des populations et les flèches en rouge indiquent les paramètres influençant négativement les populations. Le cercle bleu représente la capacité d'accueil, paramètre limitant les populations.](D:\lea_s\Documents\Biologie Montaury\Master STAAE\M1\S1\Dynamique des populations\Devoir final\Capture.png)
```

However, it doesn't work at all. In R Markdown, the picture is displayed but when I convert the file to HTML, the picture is replaced by a little broken image.
I've tried to change the size but it doesn't work either. The picture and my R Markdown's file are in the same directory.

I don't know if it's relevant, my R Markdown contains a Shinyapp.

```
---
title: "Impact sur la population d'une araignée *Dysdera crocata* des nouveaux entrepôts Amazon<sup>®</sup> "
author: "Léa Simonet"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(),'%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
runtime : shiny
---
```

Do you have an idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have BOTH files reside in the same directory. If your image is on the flash drive, you will need to save your .Rmd file in the same directory on the flash drive and have the image be a relative file path.

Comment: Yes they are already in the same directory. My "D:" is a USB driver and inside I have a file who contains the image and the .rmd file.

Comment: This path : "D:\lea_s\Documents\Biologie Montaury\Master STAAE\M1\S1\Dynamique des populations\Devoir final\Nouveau dossier\"     is the same for the image and for .rmd file

Comment: What message in the console? it worked on my computer with your code. Were you ever able to get this to work or is this the first time? Have you tried moving the files to your desktop to see if you can run it there? I wonder if there is some permission issues or something.

Comment: Oh I didn't see it before but there is this message in the console : " Warning in file.create(to[okay]) :
  impossible de créer le fichier 'C:\Users\Lea\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp88iDRo\file19ec26b5216e_files/D:/lea_s/Documents/Biologie Montaury/Master STAAE/M1/S1/Dynamique des populations/Devoir final/Nouveau dossier/Capture.png', à cause de 'Invalid argument'        So, I don't understand because I've checked so many times that the working directory is the same that the image but I don't know why the Output  is not the same... Sorry I'm a little lost

Comment: This is the first time and I've tried in my destop but same problem.

Comment: You might need to look into resetting your R session, and clearing the cache

Comment: It doesn't work....The only thing I know it's that the path of html output is wrong but I don't how to change because  I've already changed the working directory